# Manage alignment in custom font in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

I am using custom font in my code. After using it, letters are not aligned in one line which is causing UI issues.
[image]

I want to change font or label setting so that it look like below : 
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is due to the `Font` style so you can set the text as `NSAttributedString` String and manage the Font accordingly. In that case create two `NSMutableAttributedString` with different `Attributes`and use it.

```
extension String    {

    func getText() -> NSAttributedString {
        let str1 = "Hello"
        let str2 = "750"

        //create attribute
        let attStr1      = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str1)
        let attFormat   = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)]
        let attString   = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str2, attributes: attFormat)
        attString.appendAttributedString(attStr1)

        return attString
    }
}
```

Just create `Attribute` according to your requirement and it will work.